# How to display tag on top of article and author at the bottom

Tags: joomla-3.4, articles, layout

I would like to display the tags at the top of the article but the author at the bottom. One way to do that would be to tweak the `split` option for `Position of Article Info` in `Article Manager Options`, because it displays the tags below and the author above (I would just have to find the `.php` doing this and exchange the code for tags and author).

● If you think this is the best way to do it, where is this `php`?

● If you think there is a better way to do  what I want, how could I do it?

I looked into `templates\proto\html\com_content\article\default.php` (or to be accurate, an override of this file) but I could find a code setting up the position of article info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set position of info *above* to keep tags in that position and make an override of `com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php` with this changes:

*Line 76 - remove or comment this statement:*

```
echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.info_block.block', array('item' => $this->item, 'params' => $params, 'position' => 'above'));
```

in this way the view will not load author and other info in this position

Add statement to print author where you want to display it with this code:

```
echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.info_block.author', array('item' => $this->item, 'params' => $params, 'position' => 'below'));
```

**JLayoutHelper** refers to the file path of the first parameter, in this case refers to `/layouts/joomla/content/info_block/author.php`

Anyway it's better to use an override instead of editing core files.

Comment: Thanks for this! Yes it worked!However, I use a plugin (Disqus by JW) which is loaded just below `<div itemprop="articleBody"><?php echo $this->item->text; ?>`. Even if I move your statement just below this piece of code (around line 118), I still get my author name below the plugin. How can I modify my `default.php` override to get `my article`, then `my author` and then `my plugin`? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Make an override of _/plugins/content/jw_disqus/jw_disqus/tmpl/article.php_ in your template folder _/html/jw_disqus/article.php_. In this file _echo $row->text_ actually prints the article content, so just add the statement to show the article's author where you need (replacing $this->item with $row): `echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.info_block.author', array('item' => $row, 'params' => $params, 'position' => 'below'));`

Comment: Thanks you so much! I have ask the same question here: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/15915/how-to-display-to-tweak-a-plugin-so-it-will-load-below-the-author so you can share your answer.