# How to tweak a plugin so it will load below the author?

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, overrides

I use an override of  com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php to display the author name below the article text:

```
<div itemprop="articleBody">
<?php echo $this->item->text;?>
<?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.info_block.author', array('item' => $this->item, 'params' => $params, 'position' => 'below')); ?>
</div>
```

But I also use a plugin (Disqus by JW) which is loaded just below

```
<div itemprop="articleBody"><?php echo $this->item->text; ?>.
```

So the current order is:

- Article
- Disqus comment
- Author

How can I force the Disqus plugin to load below the author name so I get in this order:

- Article
- Author
- Disqus comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in this [question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/15854/how-to-display-tag-on-top-of-article-and-author-at-the-bottom/15893#15893):

Make an override of `/plugins/content/jw_disqus/jw_disqus/tmpl/article.php` in your template folder `/html/jw_disqus/article.php`.

In this file `echo $row->text` actually prints the article content, so just add the statement to show the article's author where you need (replacing `$this->item` with `$row`):

```
echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.info_block.author', array('item' => $row, 'params' => $params, 'position' => 'below'));
```

**JLayoutHelper** refers to the file path of the first parameter, in this case refers to `/layouts/joomla/content/info_block/author.php`

Answer (score 0):

It may be simpler to reorder the elements using CSS without having to create an override.

There are a few ways to do this. See [Swap DIV position with CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17455811/1983389) for some options.